# error C2244 unable to match function definition to an existing declaration while using templates

Tags: c++, templates

So I have this Binary Search tree that I want to define with templates. those are the headers:

```
template <class T>
class BSNode
{
public:
    BSNode(T data);
    BSNode(const BSNode& other);
    virtual ~BSNode();
    virtual BSNode* insert(T value);
    BSNode& operator=(const BSNode& other);
    bool isLeaf() const;
    T getData() const;
    BSNode* getLeft() const;
    BSNode* getRight() const;
    bool search(T val) const;
    int getDepth(const BSNode& root) const;
    void printNodes() const; 


protected:
    T _data;
    BSNode* _left;
    BSNode* _right;
    int _count; // if there are duplicated items.
    int BSNode::getCurrNodeDistFromInputNode(const BSNode* node) const; // help func to get depth.

};
```

But for some reason I always get an "unable to match definition" error in the getters or "use of class templates requires arguement list"

for example, this code yields an "unable to match definition" error.

```
template<class T>
BSNode* BSNode<T>::getLeft() const
{
    return this->_left;
}


template<class T>
BSNode* BSNode<T>::getRight() const
{
    return this->_right;
}
```

This code yields "use of class templates requires argument list":

```
template<class T>
BSNode* BSNode<T>::insert(T value)
{

    // check where should insert the node - right or left
    if (value < this->_data)
    {
        if (_left) // if there is already left son
        {
            _left = _left->insert(value); // recursive call on the left son
        }
        else
        {
            _left = new BSNode(value); // add the node as left son
            return *this;
        }
    }
    else if (value > this->_data)
    {
        if (_right) // if there is already right son
        {
            _right = _right->insert(value); // recursive call on the right son
        }
        else
        {
            _right = new BSNode(value); // add the node as right son
            return *this;
        }
    }
    else //value == this->_data
    {
        this->_count++;
        return *this;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I am pretty sure my problem lies with the signatures, but still i post the full code. Can somebody help me understand why am I getting this problems and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've left out the `<T>` in several places. It's required in most places outside the class definition.

Comment: Don't paraphrase the error. Incude it verbatim.

Comment: And show precisely the line, at which the error is raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the compiler already knows you're inside the context of `BSNode` you need to provide the template arguments - so for example

```
template<class T>
BSNode<T>* BSNode<T>::getLeft() const
{
    return this->_left;
}
```

Yes, this feels a bit repetitive. You can make it less verbose by defining the member functions inside the class definition. (Although some people also dislike that for stylistic reasons.)